# How to disable workflow on sharepoint list 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I've a workflow on a SharePoint list, triggered manually and when an item is created.

I don't want to remove it but just disable.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not intiating the workflow when the item is created or modified from the designer. In the designer go to the list chosse workflows, then uncheck when to start the workflow when new item is created and and also uncheck when you edit/update the listitem

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to run workflow on other newely created items then 
1. Go to Worklow Setting
2. Click on Remove, Block or restore workflow.
3. Select option No New Instances.
4. Click ok